# adjusting row height in R image() function

Tags: image, r, heatmap

I'm drawing several heatmaps using the image() function in R. 
The sizes of the heatmaps are quite variable, so every heatmap has a different height, however I want the row heights be uniform across heatmaps. 
So I create heatmaps from these two matrices, and the heights of each cell are different between two heatmaps:

```
m1<-replicate(40, rnorm(20))     
image(1:ncol(m1), 1:nrow(m1), t(m1), axes = FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")


m2<-replicate(40, rnorm(10))
image(1:ncol(m2), 1:nrow(m2), t(m2), axes = FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
```

For the life of me, I can't figure out how can I specify the row height. It must be a very easy fix, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You give very limited information. E.g., do you want to create PDFs? Or place several plots on one page?

Here is one solution:

```
par(fin=c(5,5),mar=c(0,0,0,0))
image(1:ncol(m1), 1:nrow(m1), t(m1), axes = FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")

par(fin=c(5,2.5),mar=c(0,0,0,0))
image(1:ncol(m2), 1:nrow(m2), t(m2), axes = FALSE,xlab="",ylab="")
```

I am sure there are more elegant solutions depending on what you actually want to do with the graphs.

Comment: I just need to create tens of these heatmaps, and save them individually as pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a common maximum number of rows for all the heatmaps using the `ylim` parameter:

```
m1<-replicate(40, rnorm(20))     
m2<-replicate(40, rnorm(10))

image(1:ncol(m1), 1:nrow(m1), t(m1), axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE, ylim=c(0, max(sapply(list(m1,m2),nrow)) ))
image(1:ncol(m2), 1:nrow(m2), t(m2), axes=FALSE, ann=FALSE, ylim=c(0, max(sapply(list(m1,m2),nrow)) ))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to manually specify the `ylim` argument and have that be the same between the 2 plots:

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))

image( 0:ncol(m1), 0:nrow(m1), t(m1), axes=FALSE, xlab='', ylab='', 
        ylim=c(0,nrow(m1)) )
image( 0:ncol(m2), 0:nrow(m2), t(m2), axes=FALSE, xlab='', ylab='',
        ylim=c(0,nrow(m1)) )
```